# Why does the deployment of smart contracts on the private Ethereum blockchain need to consume gas fee, while the invocation does not?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

Why does the deployment of smart contracts on the private Ethereum chain need to consume gasoline, while the invocation does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're deploying a contract, you're sending a [transaction](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_sendtransaction), effectively storing the contract bytecode in the network. All transactions cost gas fees as a reward for the miner/validator who executes it and publishes it to the network.

When you're invoking a contract function, you can do it two ways:

- read-only gas-free [call](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_call) that is not processed by a miner/validator - only by a node that your app is connected to. You don't pay any gas fees, but also cannot store any changes (e.g. token transfers)
- read-write transaction that costs gas fees as a reward for the miner/validator

Comment: If I am the owner of this private blockchain, is the gas fees paid by me for publishing the smart contract for me?

Comment: @NFx On private blockchains, that depends on the chain configuration. But unless you have configured otherwise, the gas fees are generally paid by you for publishing the smart contract for you (and possibly claimed back by you as the miner).

Comment: If it is on the private blockchain, should I pay the gas fee in Ethereum or my customized virtual currency？

Comment: @NFx Gas fees are by default paid in the native currency of the network. So unless you set up your private network otherwise, the default option is whatever is the native currency of your private network.